# Trying to write a regex for aaa!bb@123&xyz#--

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace every individual character in my string with a space, that is not among following,

- digit 0 to 9
- english letter both uppercase and lowercase
- these special characters `: &'(),-._`

For e.g. if my initial string is,

```
aaa!bb@123&xyz#--
```

then it should become,

```
aaa bb 123&xyz --
```

Can someone provide a regular expression for achieving same?

Comment: Regex doesn’t “do” anything; it is used to match strings. You need an app language to “do” something, like replace chars. What app language are you using?

Comment: and where is you Java code, where is the regex?

Comment: Can you share your progress with sample code or regex that you could come up with?

Comment: _"In case the string's characters is not among the valid ones I have to replace it with blank"_. Does this mean you want to set the **whole** string to blank (space?) or just the characters that are not in the allowed set of characters. Is the double-quote character itself allowed or not? Show us an example string and the desired output at least..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negated character set and put all characters that you don't want to get replaced with a space. Rest any character will be replaced with a space. Here is the Java code for same.

```
String s = "abc#1$xyz";
System.out.println("Before: " + s);
System.out.println("After:  " + s.replaceAll("[^\\w &'(),.:-]", " "));
```

Which prints following output,

```
Before: abc#1$xyz
After:  abc 1 xyz
```

As you can see `#` and `$` are not in the negated character set, hence they are replaced with a space.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the answer I was looking for

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `.replaceAll`. This method looks for each of the regex matches in your string and replaces them with another string.

Your code will look like this:

```
String str = "Text/containing+invalid=characters";
String cleanStr = str.replaceAll("[^&'\\(\\),\\-.0-9:A-Z_a-z]", " ");
System.out.println(cleanStr);
```

More info [here](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace.shtml)

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the answer I was looking for